# Flex and associative arrays indexed by Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, associative-array

**Environment: Flex 3.6**

Look at this piece of code:

```
    var arr:Array = new Array()
    var t:Object = {number:"12345", id:"Public"};
    arr[t] = "Hello";

    for (var z:Object in arr)
    {
        if (z is String)
            trace("STRING");
        if (z is Object)
            trace("OBJECT");
        trace("z.number = " + z.number);
    }
```

output:

```
STRING
OBJECT
```

then crashes on the last `trace()` call with the error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property number not found on String and there is no default value
```

Isn't the Object supposed to preserve the name of fields?
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `for(var key)` loop for the `Array` object `key` is always `String`.  You can use `Dictionary` then `key` will be the type of Object and your code will works:

```
 var arr:Dictionary= new Dictionary()
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys to arrays are usually numbers.
The line:

```
arr[t] = "Hello";
```

Is probably not doing what you expect as it's taking the object t and converting it to a string to use as key in the array. The object it gets converted to the string "[object Object]".

There's several issues in this code:

```
for (var z:Object in arr)
{
    if (z is String)
        trace("STRING");
    if (z is Object)
        trace("OBJECT");
    trace("z.number = " + z.number);
}
```

Z should be of type String not Object, but if you want to look at each item in the array and you want for use a for each loop rather than a for loop. As the array can contain different types z needs to be of the type "*".

Lastly the trace of z.number is being run no matter what type z is it should only be run if z is an Object. (And also assuming all objects in the array have a number property.)

```
arr[0] = "Hello";
arr[1] = t;

for each (var z:* in arr)
{
    if (z is String)
        trace("STRING");

    if (z is Object) {
        trace("OBJECT");
        trace("z.number = " + z.number);
     }
}
```